# How to prevent Gnome apps from removing title bar when maximized?

Tags: gnome3

As of Gnome 3.6, Files (previously known as Nautilus) removes its title bar when maximized. Several other Gnome apps that I generally don't use also do this, e.g. Epiphany.

Is there a way I can stop them from doing this, so that when I maximize an app, it would still have a title bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that a preference "ignore-request-hide-titlebar" was [added in 3.6](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678947). Unfortunately the preference is not loaded from gsettings, so I wrote an extension to set it: https://github.com/garyvdm/gnome_shell_ignore_request_hide_titlebar